# How's the JS client API of parse.com working?

Tags: javascript, cors

I saw this article: http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/playing-parsecom-api, and I liked their example JS code:

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username", "ElMacho");
user.set("password", "chicken");
user.set("email", "el@macho.name");

user.signUp(null, {
  success: function(user) {
    // Everything's done!
    console.log(user.id);
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

I'd like to understand how this works, and to confirm my hunch. Did they enable CORS on their servers, to make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can check yourself :)

Open up fiddler or some other network traffic analyser. If there is an OPTIONS call made with CORS headers then you will know it is using CORS. I would suggest that it must be if the request is being made cross origin.

Comment: Not all CORS requests are preflighted.